# _source column is getting removed from OpenSearch when a new column is added

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

Whenever I add a new column, _source is getting removed and I can't add it back
When I remove all the added columns, _source column is automatically added
How can I prevent _source column from being removed?

[Before adding any column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvhFg.png)

[When a new column is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiYVb.png)

_source column should stay with all the other columns added

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.